# ASP.NET MVC view not displaying correct info from database

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

So I am building a report to be displayed on our website, I created a view for the qry and dropping it into our .EDMX file.  I can set up the view for the site with that query however the data in the database is not matching up with what is being shown on screen.  The dates are what is messing up, everything else matches.  Any thoughts as to what is wrong?

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [Name]
  ,[Manufacturer]
  ,[SerialNumber]
  ,[TSIFBarcode]
  ,[NextCalibrationDate]
  ,[Description]
  ,[CalibrationCost]
  ,[Location]
  ,[RoutineInspection]
  ,[Comment]
  ,[Priority]
FROM [InsertDBHere]
```

That is my sql code, below is my code to create the view from my controller:

```
IEnumerable<qryCalibrationEquipmentTracker> view = db.qryCalibrationEquipmentTrackers;
view = view.OrderBy(a => a.NextCalibrationDate);
return View(view);
```

Below is code for the view

```
@model IEnumerable<MvcDBFirst.Models.qryCalibrationEquipmentTracker>
@{    
     ViewBag.Title = "Calibration Tracking Report";
 }
<h2>Calibration Tracking Report</h2>
@if (ViewBag.PrintMode == null || !ViewBag.PrintMode)
{
<div class="float-right clear-fix">
    <div class="amMenu">
        <ul class="amMenuLinksHoriz clear-fix">
            <li>
                <a href="@Url.Action("ExportCalTracking", "Reports")">
                    <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/assetmgr/printer.png")" height="25px" alt="Printer" />
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                @*<a href="@Url.Action("ExcelCalTracking", "Reports")">*@
                <a onclick="postTableData('amCalIndexTable')">
                    <img src="@Url.Content("~/images/assetmgr/excel.png")" height="25px" alt="Excel" />
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
}


<h2>Report Run on @DateTime.Now.ToString()</h2>
   <table class="amCalIndexTable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Manufacturer)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.SerialNumber)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TSIFBarcode)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.NextCalibrationDate)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Priority)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.CalibrationCost)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Location)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.RoutineInspection)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Comment)
        </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Manufacturer)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.SerialNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TSIFBarcode)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.NextCalibrationDate)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Priority)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
                @*Html.ActionLink(item.Description, "Details", "tblItems",
                        new
                        {
                            type = item.fkItemType,
                            serialNumber = item.SerialNumber,
                            owner = item.fkOwner
                        }, null
                    )*@
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CalibrationCost)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Location)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.RoutineInspection)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Comment)
            </td>

        </tr>
    }
</tbody>
```

Comment: How are the dates "messing up"?  We can't see your screen from here, you need to specify the problem.  There's nothing wrong with the code shown.

Comment: so here is some dates from the database
`2013-05-14 00:00:00
2013-10-07 00:00:00
2014-11-11 00:00:00
NULL
2015-11-05 00:00:00`

those are correct, but on the view they will only come up as 
`2015-10-07`
for ALL 5 of them

Comment: show your code for the MVC View

Comment: @Neal: There's nothing in the posted code which would cause that.

Comment: I have added the view code

Comment: Maybe it's possible, that the `NULL` value in your dates is causing the `OrderBy` to yield the successful orderings but the exits?

Comment: if I dont orderby the dates are still wrong

Answer (score 0):

Convert your `view` to List before the `OrderBy` like this. `view.ToList().OrderBy()`.

Like this.

```
IEnumerable<qryCalibrationEquipmentTracker> view = db.qryCalibrationEquipmentTrackers;
view = view.ToList().OrderBy(a => a.NextCalibrationDate);
return View(view);
```

Comment: they still have the same dates

Answer (score 0):

This was a Microsoft issue, since it was a query it didnt have a primary key.  Microsoft came in and randomly chose a primary key.  We have updated our query to deal with this.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if I have to bet in here, the problem was probably in your code and not in Microsoft's...

Comment: Well everyone else here is saying the code is right.  And after doing what I stated it worked